# beautifulsoup parsing array of objects

Tags: beautifulsoup

The soup object that I get from one url looks like:

```
<html><body><p>[
    {
        "id": "...", 
        "Version": "...", 
        "Product": ".", 
    }, 
    {
        "id": "...", 
        "Version": "...", 
        "Product": ".", 
    }]
</p></body></html>
```

My goal is to parse the objects and store them in an array.

I tried

```
for res in soup.find("body").find_all('p'):
    print(res)
```

But the single `res` contains all objects instead of being a separate object.

How can I parse each object separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a example :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ast

html_string = """
<html><body><p>[
    {
        "id": "...",
        "Version": "...",
        "Product": ".",
    },
    {
        "id": "...",
        "Version": "...",
        "Product": ".",
    }
    ]
</p></body></html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, "html.parser")
samples = soup.find_all("p")

for row in samples:
    liststring=row.get_text()

# convert this string into list
res = ast.literal_eval(liststring)
print(res)

for x in res:
    print(x)
```